# spark java.io.IOException: There is not enough space on the disk

Tags: python, apache-spark, logistic-regression

I was running a logistic regression algorithm on a 8 nodes spark cluster, each node has 8 cores and 56 GB Ram (each node is running windows system). And the spark installation driver has 1.9 TB capacity. The dataset I was training on are has around 40 million records with around 6600 features. But I always get this error during the training process:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o70.trainLogisticRegressionModelWithLBFGS.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2709 in stage 3.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2709.3 in stage 3.0 (TID 2766, workernode0.rbaHdInsightCluster5.b6.internal.cloudapp.net): java.io.IOException: There is not enough space on the disk
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:345)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:122)
        at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyOutputStream.dumpOutput(SnappyOutputStream.java:300)
        at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyOutputStream.rawWrite(SnappyOutputStream.java:247)
        at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyOutputStream.write(SnappyOutputStream.java:107)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(ObjectOutputStream.java:1876)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.writeByte(ObjectOutputStream.java:1914)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFatalException(ObjectOutputStream.java:1575)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:350)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:42)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationStream.writeAll(Serializer.scala:110)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.dataSerializeStream(BlockManager.scala:1177)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskStore.putIterator(DiskStore.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:787)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.putIterator(BlockManager.scala:638)
        at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.putInBlockManager(CacheManager.scala:145)
        at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.getOrCompute(CacheManager.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:243)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.FilteredRDD.compute(FilteredRDD.scala:34)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:278)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:245)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:200)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1214)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1203)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1202)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1202)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:696)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:696)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:696)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessActor$$anonfun$receive$2.applyOrElse(DAGScheduler.scala:1420)
        at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:465)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessActor.aroundReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1375)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:487)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:238)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:220)
        at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:393)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

The code is below:

```
from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint
from pyspark.mllib.classification import LogisticRegressionWithSGD
from numpy import array
from sklearn.feature_extraction import FeatureHasher
from pyspark import SparkContext
sf = SparkConf().setAppName("test").set("spark.executor.memory", "45g").set("spark.cores.max", 62)
sc = SparkContext(conf=sf)
training_file = sc.textFile("train_small.txt")
def hash_feature(line):
    values = [0, dict()]
    for index, x in enumerate(line.strip("\n").split('\t')):
        if index == 0:
            values[0] = float(x)
        else:
            values[1][str(index)+"_"+x] = 1
    return values
n_feature = 2**14
hasher = FeatureHasher(n_features=n_feature)
training_file_hashed = training_file.map(lambda line: [hash_feature(line)[0], hasher.transform([hash_feature(line)[1]])])
def build_lable_points(line):
    values = [0.0] * n_feature
    for index, value in zip(line[1].indices, line[1].data):
        values[index] = value
    return LabeledPoint(line[0], values)
parsed_training_data = training_file_hashed.map(lambda line: build_lable_points(line))
model = LogisticRegressionWithSGD.train(parsed_training_data)
```

Can anyone share any experience with this?

Comment: Use the `df` command to see if you have filled up the disk.  It might be nothing to do with the application itself.

Comment: Can you be more specific as I am new to spark, what is the "df" command? I can not get anything on it when search it.

Comment: Thanks, I am using windows system. And I will log into one worknode and check.the disk.

Comment: I've hit the same, while training random forest on spark, but in my case that was a write shuffles spilled on disk into a temporary partition. Even though spark clears it all up after the particular stage, starting from a specific stage it's completely filled up and there is literally no more disk space available.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, that is the cause.

Answer (score 1):

The size of RDD doesn't always match the input file size. In your case, RDD of your data set is bigger than the capacity of the file system Spark uses to persist it.

Try with smaller data set and gradually increase the size, while checking Spark web UI's RDD size information. (To find spark web UI URL, search for "http" in the output of your Spark log)